# Creating custom panel page gives page not found error

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels

I have been striving hard to make this work.I have created a custom panel page with the page url as `taxonomy/term/%term/content-type/how-to.`
So i have this via pathauto url
`Vocab : Category`
`Parent term: food`
`Child term : pizza`

After setting up the panel page when i go to 
`www.example.com/category/food/pizza/content-type/how-to` it gives me `404 error(page not found).`

And when i manually set up a custom panel page for each url(for e.g `www.example.com/category/food/pizza/content-type/how-to`)  it is working fine.

Can you guys point out whats wrong with`taxonomy/term/%term/content-type/how-to` url ?

Comment: If this is a custom page panel, do you also have the 'in code" version with taxonomy/term/%term enabled?

Answer (score 2):

The most common and likely reason is that you have not assigned a context to your %term argument. This causes Page manager to reject the term argument, failing to find the path, and finally returning a 404. There's a similar issue [here](http://drupal.org/node/1230238).

I could tell more specifically if you provided an export of the Panel.

Comment: Yep, fixed my problem - selected "String" as the context. (would this be a more sensible default?)

Comment: @artfulrobot You don't generally want "String" contexts. One looses a lot of possibly intelligent behaviour, for example identifying the string as a valid term and giving a 404 for non-existing terms.

Comment: Sure, but they have their uses. (hence their existence.)

Comment: @artfulrobot They do, I just wanted to suggest that I think they'd make a bad default choice. :)